# Retriving a file from MS Server 2005 using Java

Tags: java, database, audio, sql-server-2005

What I'm trying to do is when a user hits a link with the correct parameters, the system will retrieve the file from the MS Server 2005 db and outputs it to the user. Specifically, I stored an audio file in varbinary data type and now I have the ID to retrieve the audio file but I don't know what is the Java command to output it for the user.

My code is written in Java and I tried to search for a similar topic on here but had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
-Bao

Comment: Is this a web app or is your link in a client app?

Comment: Please post what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is the solution that did the job for me. Basically I had to use the javax.sound.sampled.* API. This is what I did below:

```
    InputParameters parameters = parts.getParameters();
    int audioFileID = parameters.getIntParameter("audiofileID");

    //Retrieves Audio File
    AudioFile audioFile = CallManager.getAudioFile(audioFileID);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioFile.getAudio());

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
  audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, audioInputStream);
    }

    AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream,javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,byteOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one example for file downloading here, maybe is helpful:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/154128

Maybe you can try to combine that with your link handler.